# How to delete user without posts in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on L5.5 and I need to delete user but not his/her posts. So I basically need to assign his/her posts to another user which has to be Non-removable.

What I need:

1. Create a user which can't be deleted at least not from front-end even by owner of website but can be edited. (mostly is like bot for this application)
2. If I delete a user and that user had post(s) those post(s) remain and assign to this user (bot). It means this bot will become author of those posts.
3. Check for number 2 that only if user with post that happens if user has no post just delete him/her.

This is my usecontroller destroy method currently:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        Storage::delete($user->image);
        $user->delete();
        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('flash_message', 'User successfully deleted');
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need `softDeletes` in your model https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: @NitishKumar thanks bro that was more like suggestion, I need answer even if i use soft delete what about the rest of my needs such as assign posts to other user etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your needs, you will require `softDeletes` in your `User` model and their respective tables in the database, now this solves your 1st problem where your not deleting the user from table simply adding deleted_at column.

**Edit:** As you are using `Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait` you need to have your user model look something like this:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableInterface
{
    use Authenticatable;
    use EntrustUserTrait { restore as private restoreA; }
    use SoftDeletes { restore as private restoreB; }

    public function restore()
    {
        $this->restoreA();
        $this->restoreB();
    }
}
```

For more information about this error you need to look: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/742

so now coming to the 2nd point, retrieving the post with deleted model can be used `withTrashed()` something like:

```
$user = User::withTrashed()->all();
$user = User::withTrashed()->where('id', 1);

$posts = $user->posts()->get();
// Or do your relational things
```

Even if you want to assign it to different user then you need to create a new user and apply update methods to all the relational model while deleting the user which seems a bad idea.

**Edit:**

So in this case you can have:

```
$oldUser = User::find($id);
$user = User::find($botID); // Find the bot user

$oldFoods = $oldUser->food()->get();
foreach($oldFoods as $food)
{
    $food->user_id = $user->id;
    $food->save();
}
```

Now for your 3rd point if the user has no post then you can do a small check something like this:

```
$user = User::find($request->id);
$posts = $user->posts()->get()->first();
if(isset($posts))
{
    $user->delete();
}
else
{
    $user->forceDelete();
}
```

Hope this justifies all your needs.

**Conclusion** So fnally you can have your `destroy` method in `userController` as:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $foods = $user->food()->get();
    if(isset($foods))
    {
       $botUser = User::where('username', '=', 'bot'); // Find the bot user
        foreach($foods as $food)
        {
            $food->user_id = $botUser->id;
            $food->save();
        }
        $user->delete();
    }
    else
    {
        $user->forceDelete();
    }
    Storage::delete($user->image);
    return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('flash_message', 'User successfully deleted');
}
```

Comment: hi bro, thanks for answer i have some questions, 1. which method this goes to `$user = User::withTrashed();
$posts = $user->posts()->get();`?  2. It's not really bad idea even WordPress using this feature `Even if you want to assign it to different user then you need to create a new user and apply update methods to all the relational model while deleting the user which seems a bad idea.` how can I do that?

Comment: @mafortis What is the relationship you are having between user and posts?

Comment: user model `public function food(){ return $this->hasMany(Food::class);    }`  food model `public function user(){ return $this->belongsTo(User::class);  }`

Comment: I assume they are in different controllers right? would you please tell me what controller and what method i should place your codes to test it? `note` when i add `softdelete` to my user model i get this error `Trait method restore has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\User`

Comment: ps: i have this additional trait `use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;` using it for my roles and permissions.

Comment: @mafortis implementing in controllers needs to defined by you, where you want to use it? or how you want to use it?, we can only guide you, and regarding the `User` model error I've updated the answer, please go through the link. Hope this helps.

Comment: My point wasn't that you tell me step by step, I meant I'm confuse with your codes cause there is no `public function xxxx() {` before them so i really don't know where should i place them in index, in show, in store etc. and in this case i have 2 controllers `usercontroller` and `foodcontroller` so not sure for eg. this one is for which one `$user = User::withTrashed()->all();
$user = User::withTrashed()->where('id', 1);

$posts = $user->posts()->get();` I hope i could be clear.

Comment: @mafortis since you asked for which method it goes into, I tried explaining the eloquent methods which can be used along with this, no problem, generally `withTrashed` will be used while fetching the `food()`  it might be your `index` where you are showing all the data i.e. `User::withTrashed()->all()`, it might be `edit` method, where you are calling single food element i.e. `User::withTrashed()->where('id', 1);` So I don't know which method of your controller defines what action. That is why briefed the answer with guidance.

Comment: @mafortis if you can share the controllers I'll guide you where you can use what.

Comment: @mafortis Do you want to edit deleted users too? if that so then you can use `$user = User::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);` in your `public function edit()` method rest looks fine and show me `foodController` too.

Comment: no i just need restore function for deleted user and forcedelete function.   here is `foodcontroller`  https://codeshare.io/a3oDwB  and one thing i tested this it soft delete my user fine but i'm not see any option for moving posts to another user.

Comment: @mafortis you will have to create the `user` in destroy method itself before deleting the user model. I've edited the answer you need to have `destroy` method in `userController` something like mentioned above.

Comment: @mafortis Updated the latest code, previous one was creating new food models, which I guess you don't require, you simply require the user_id to be changed. Please have a look.

Comment: there is an issue here in this code, this will make user on delete which will be duplicated after first user delete, i need to assign an existed user not to create one every time i delete someone.

Comment: @mafortis no problem, remove the create method and just find that particular user and assign it to that.

Comment: :-p how...? :-D and one more thing food user_id didnt change to new user that created

Comment: do you know the id of that particular existing user?

Comment: i prefer to use username rather than id, id could be different in any website. the username will be `bot`

Comment: Does the `username bot` unique? as while fetching through that it will give other rows too, I mean multiple models. then how it will be allocated to any food?

Comment: username field is unique. i think instead of creating user we have to call the bot user name and in `if(isset($foods))` before save change `$food->user_id = $user->id;` to `bot->id`

Comment: No, first of all you need to find the user with `username bot`. I've updated the answer, please check the conclusion part.

Comment: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154511/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 0):

Edit your database with

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('restrict')
                    ->onUpdate('restrict');
```

Comment: in which part? and why please?